# Finding $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan^2(\sqrt x)}{x} $ ; Is my approach correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I'm just starting off with analysis, so I'm still not really familiar with everything. I want to find $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan^2(\sqrt x)}{x} $$

I know I can use l'Hospital, since I have the $ \frac {0}{0} $ case. Then I get:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan^2(\sqrt x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan(\sqrt x)}{\cos ^2(\sqrt x) \sqrt x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{(2\cos ^2(\sqrt x) \sqrt x)(\frac{\cos^2(\sqrt x)}{2\sqrt x}+\cos(\sqrt x)(-\sin(\sqrt x))} = \frac{1}{0} \cdot\frac{1}{\frac{1}{0}+0} = \frac{1}{0} = \infty$$

Is that correct? It took me really long and it feels like I made it more complicated than it should've been.

Please help me out here, I'd be grateful for any answers/ comments! :)

Comment: You made a mistake when you wrote $0\cdot\left(\frac{1}{0}+0\right)=0$. $0\cdot(1/0)$ is an indeterminate form (and I personally hate the notation). In general, L'Hopital's rule is nice to be aware of but can get quite messy. It's often better to use low-order Taylor expansions.

Comment: @FShrike Oh, I understand. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries. Use `\cdot` for multiplication, usually using $\ast$ in this context looks ugly. Compare: $$1\cdot2$$With $$1\ast2$$(and then you get to use $\ast$ to mean other things)

Comment: @FShrike Thanks again! I'm new here so I still have to figure out some things... ^^'

Comment: The limit is $1$. Also you can use the expansion in $x=0$ of $\tan(\sqrt x)$ which is equal to $$\sqrt x+\frac{x^{3/2}}{3}+O(x^{5/2})$$ so you have
$$\frac{\tan^2(\sqrt x)}{x}=\frac{x+\frac{2x^2}{3}+O(x^3)}{x}$$ where you can see the limit $1$

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, you made a mistake in the last line of your computation since you've bypassed an indeterminate form. Personally, I don't like L'Hopital's Rule and I try to avoid it at all costs. In this particular limit, I think it's an overkill to use it since you can solve your problem using only the fundamental limit.

Using the fact that
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{1}{\cos x}=1$$
you have:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\tan^2 \sqrt x}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\tan \sqrt x}{\sqrt x}\frac{\tan \sqrt x}{\sqrt x}=1 $$

Comment: "Is that correct?" They asked for a proof verification, if only they knew that tag existed. They did indeed make a mistake, but you should point it out

Comment: This proof makes it so much easier, I would've never thought of this. Thank you!! :)

Comment: @FShrike You're right, I wrote the answer in a rush with the intention to add more details but yesterdat I couldn't